# How to merge two pandas data.frame into one, by time index, keeping all values from both of them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series

I have to pandas dataframe with time index. One it´s a real time series and the other is an ideal time series (all the dates I want). I want to merge them by date, but keeping all values, even the NaN values.

Creating the real time series:

```
start_date = '2019-01-01'
end_date = '2020-01-01'
rows,cols = 51,1
data = np.random.rand(51)
tidx = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=rows, freq='16d')
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['EVI'], index=tidx)
print(data_frame)
```

Output:

```
EVI
2019-01-01  0.395097
2019-01-17  0.300081
2019-02-02  0.080104
......
......
```

Creating the ideal time series with NaN values (I just want the index)

```
ideal_tidx = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='8d')
dummy_data = np.empty((ideal_tidx.size))
dummy_data[:] = np.nan
dummy_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data, columns=['EVI'], index=ideal_tidx)
```

Output:

```
            EVI
2019-01-01  NaN
2019-01-09  NaN
2019-01-17  NaN
....
```

I want to merge to have something like this:

```
  EVI
2019-01-01  0.395097
2019-01-09  NaN
2019-01-17  0.300081
2019-01-25  NaN
2019-02-02  0.080104
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use outer join and then drop unnecessary column of your dummy dataframe

```
df = data_frame.merge(dummy_data_frame, left_index =True, rigth_index=True, how='outer',
    suffixes = ('', '_dummy'))
df.drop(columns='EVI_dummy', inplace=True)
```